# CSS Table Images Have Spaces

Tags: html, css

I have an email template here and the issue is that my divider images they have spaces on the top and bottom.

I am trying to figure this out on how to remove the spaces on the top and bottom of the divider image. Also I want to know how can I put borders on each element.

```
    <tr><td width="100%"><img src="img/divider.png" class="deviceWidth"/> </td> </tr>
```

You can check my JS FIDDLE DEMO HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/YTvqb/

NOTE: the divider are the lines that have different color on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `display: block` to the img will get rid of that extra space. By default, images are inline which causes them to leave room for letter descenders. Making them block removes the space for the descenders.

http://jsfiddle.net/YTvqb/1/

Comment: I have one more question for you how can I remove the borders of the IMAGE 1 and IMAGE 2 on the OUR PRODUCTS SECTION?

Comment: I don't believe those images have a border? I see a border around the broken image, but that's part of the browsers display of a broken image. If you put real images in there, that seems to go away.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="#" style="display:block;" />
```

Comment: You should add more detail to your answer.